# OpenCV Ubuntu installation undefined symbol

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

After installing OpenCV on Ubuntu I run the python code `import cv2` and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN2cv12_OutputArrayE
```

This is how I installed OpenCV.

```
mkdir opencv
cd opencv
git clone git://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

What can I do?

Comment: which gcc version is installed on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the latest release tag, rather than the HEAD code, like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv && git checkout 3.2.0
```